# BOOSTXL-DRV8323RS Set up - trying to spin motor in 3x PWM mode

Tags: arduino, motor, brushless-dc-motor, texas-instruments

I have been following the datasheet for the TI DRV8323 and the BOOSTXL-DRV8323R dev kit. I am trying to spin a BLDC motor by sending 3 SPWM waves (all 120 degrees phase shifted) generated by an arduino to the INHA, INHB, INHC pins on the DRV8323 board. As specified by the datasheet, for 3x PWM mode, I also tied the low inputs for the gate drive (INLA, INLB, INLC) to logic high, and added the 47k resistor to the MODE pin.

[image]

I checked all the input signals being sent are correct on the oscilloscope - the Arduino is correctly generating the SPWM signals.
The motor won't spin - my question is if anyone knows if I am missing a connection or if people have experience running a BLDC motor with this board.

Thanks :)

Comment: do, what's the problem? ... what do you observe?

Comment: The motor won't spin, I'm wondering if my wiring is correct

Comment: Have you checked if you have the SPI version and not the HW of DRV8323 IC.